# Keyboard shortcuts in WebForms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, keyboard-shortcuts

I am making an asp.net, c#, webforms web site for sales clerks. I have four main buttons at the top of the screen that I will be using for a lot of functions. What I want to do is set those buttons to <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F3</kbd> and <kbd>F4</kbd> keys on the keyboard.

How will this work? Can I override functions like <kbd>F1</kbd> in IE7? How do I go about implementing this? Does focus have to be on IE7?

Any and all information on this topic is appreciated.

Comment: Overriding commonly-used keys is not a good idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to do this with javascript, but there's no way that I'm aware of that will allow you to overload specific browser keys (this is a good thing). You'll still be able to use them, but there won't be a way to disable the default browser behavior. I'd re-evaluate your choice of keyboard shortcuts and see if a better solution exists.

The javascript event `onkeypress` is what you're looking for though. [Here is a solid example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp) using vanilla javscript. You can also look at [jQuery's implementation](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/).

**Update**
A new javascript library called [Kibo](https://github.com/marquete/kibo) has been released. It's a fully featured keyboard short-cut handler and would be exactly what you're looking for.